# Customize WPF application user controls

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, datagrid

I'm trying to put in my windows a Datagrid and some other things (TextBox, Dropbox).

My problem is that when I resize the windows I can't control the items.

What I want to do is to devide the Windows like the picture below, and want the them to fit the window when I resize the window.

What do you suggest.

[image: WPF App]

Comment: Are you using default WPF or MVVM pattern?

Comment: I'm not sure what this question has to do with user controls.  It certainly isn't specific to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them in [a `Grid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx) with two `RowDefinition`s.  One for the toolbar/controls at the top, the other for the `DataGrid`.

Make the first row height `Auto`, and the second row height `*`.

Set the `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` properties on the `DataGrid` to `Stretch`.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use the [Grid class](http://www.wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html).
Add Rows and Columns and change the Height and Width properties of these object to resize as you want (fixed value, Auto, *).